# Cloudformation template properties documentation discrepancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating my first Cloudformation template using an archived Github project from an AWS Blog:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/part-1-develop-deploy-and-manage-for-scale-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-cloudformation-series/
- https://github.com/amazon-archives/amediamanager

The template [amm-elasticbeanstalk.cfn.json](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amediamanager/blob/master/cfn/classic/amm-elasticbeanstalk.cfn.json) declares an Elastic Beanstalk resource, outlined here:

```
  "Resources": {
    "Application": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
      "Properties": {
        "ConfigurationTemplates": [{...}],
        "ApplicationVersions": [{...}]
      }
    }
  }
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk.html) I'm under the impression that `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion` and `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate` must be defined as separate resources, yet the example I'm working from is using the same `AWSTemplateFormatVersion` as the documentation. Is this a "shorthand" where namespaces can be nested if they have the same parent (i.e. `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk`)? Is it documented somewhere?

In the same file `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` is defined as a separate resource - is this just a stylistic choice, perhaps because the environment configuration is so long?

Comment: Does it work when you deploy it?

Comment: TIAS, good point.. I haven't tried deploying yet because I'm in the process of modifying it for my needs. But I guess I can just deploy to see and delete the stack when I'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk consists of `Applications` and `Environments` components. Basically each environment runs only one application version at a time, however, you can run the same application version in many environments at the same time. `Application versions` and `Saved configurations` are part of the `Application` resource that's why it's possible to define it within the `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application` resource properties. `Environment` however is a separate logical component of Elastic Beanstalk so it's impossible to declare it from within the `Application` resource.

For better readability I would suggest declaring all the resources separately as per this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html). Also when using this approach you can directly reference the `TemplateName` and `VersionLabel` in the `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` resource.

Alternatively if you want to stick to the github example you can adjust the above example to look like this:

```
    {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "sampleApplication": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application",
                "ApplicationVersions": [{
                    "VersionLabel": "Initial Version",
                    "Description": "Initial Version",
                    "SourceBundle": {
                        "S3Bucket": {
                            "Fn::Sub": "elasticbeanstalk-samples-${AWS::Region}"
                        },
                        "S3Key": "php-newsample-app.zip"
                    }
                }],
                "ConfigurationTemplates": [{
                    "TemplateName": "DefaultConfiguration",
                    "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template",
                    "OptionSettings": [
                        {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                            "OptionName": "MinSize",
                            "Value": "2"
                        },
                        {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                            "OptionName": "MaxSize",
                            "Value": "6"
                        },
                        {
                            "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
                            "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
                            "Value": "LoadBalanced"
                        },
                        {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
                            "Value": {
                                "Ref": "MyInstanceProfile"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.9.11 running PHP 5.5"
                }]
            }
        },
        "sampleEnvironment": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
            "Properties": {
                "ApplicationName": {
                    "Ref": "sampleApplication"
                },
                "Description": "AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment",
                "TemplateName": "DefaultConfiguration",
                "VersionLabel": "Initial Version"
            }
        },
        "MyInstanceRole": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
            "Properties": {
                "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Principal": {
                                "Service": [
                                    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Action": [
                                "sts:AssumeRole"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Description": "Beanstalk EC2 role",
                "ManagedPolicyArns": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier"
                ]
            }
        },
        "MyInstanceProfile": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
            "Properties": {
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "MyInstanceRole"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please point to a documentation which provides information on how to do it?

Comment: Great insight, thank you. I'm still curious how you came to understand that ApplicationVersions and ConfigurationTemplates are "part of the Application" while Environment is not. Is it documented, or did it come from your familiarity with Elastic Beanstalk and an implicit understanding from your knowledge? i.e. How did you put this all together?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to point out that AWS silently phased out the option of having the `ApplicationVerions` key under an `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application`'s `Properties`. It was still working in July 2022 but I noticed it stopped some time in August 2022, giving the error in the CloudFormation stack's Event tab:

> Properties validation failed for resource TheEBAppResName with message: #: extraneous key [ApplicationVersions] is not permitted

where `TheEBAppResName` is the name of your `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application` resource.

The only solution now is to follow the [current AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html) and use a separate `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion` resource.

---

Interestingly, I can't seem to find any documentation on the obsolete `ApplicationVerions` property anymore and the AWS blog that you linked to is no longer available, but I did find it [cached on the Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210726121903/https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/part-1-develop-deploy-and-manage-for-scale-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-cloudformation-series/). Even the [earliest AWS doc on GitHub for `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application`](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/blob/84118461c7a9eb29d4295be9e6afe2ca45d4c396/doc_source/aws-properties-beanstalk.md) doesn't mention the `ApplicationVerions` property. Seems like AWS silently deprecated it sometime between when the blog was posted in April 2014 and that earliest GitHub doc page in December 2017, but didn't actually remove the option until last month, August 2022.

Comment: I'm just getting back into my project after a few months away and noticed the same thing. I had to separate AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion and AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate to get it working again.